# The best free anti-virus software on ubuntu

Tags: antivirus

do I really need to install anti-virus software for Ubuntu machine? what is the recommendation for free anti-virus software?

Comment: Antivirus is mostly a windows specific problem (*malware however can impact all systems, with virus being a subset of malware*), thus the antivirus tools for GNU/Linux are generally for servers, and there to detected & remove windows viruses where the GNU/Linux system is serving files to windows client.  You didn't specify your Ubuntu product, and if you're using a Ubuntu Server that has windows clients that need protection?

Comment: Hi guiverc, yes, it's a Ubuntu server 23.10 with window client accessing. So I think anti-virus software should be installed on it.

Comment: If your windows clients have their own protection; having it also on the file-server (ie. Ubuntu) can provide another level of safety (*for the windows clients).. but it's not essential for Ubuntu.